Create a TikZ \pic depending on a dynamically created PgfplotsTable column
I want to create a TikZ \pic depending on content of a dynamically created PgfplotsTable column.
Within my MWE, I only create a very simple table via PgfplotsTable. The input data is given by a data.csv file. These data are supplemented by an additional column named "Hash". In this simple MWE, these Hash data are always the same ("TEST-Value"). Of course in the real environment, there are real Hash values calculated based on several different input data parameters.
The label of the \pic should be the calculated hash as shown in the "Expected Output" image. I try to achieve this with setting: label={\pgfplotsretval}. But it seems, that the variable \pgfplotsretval is an empty string and doesn't contain the value of the hash column.
When I replace the line with the commented one: label={TEST-Label} the label output will be "Test-Label" as expected.
So for me this is an indicator, that at this time where I read \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Hash}\of{\csvdata} the values of my Hash column are not setup / valid. Is there anyway to postpone the TikZ drawing to wait until these data are valid?
Some time ago I had a working solution, where I added all data while creating the column like this:
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[create col/assign/.code={ Add content here }]{Hash}{\csvData}

But this solution doesn't fit very well into my overall architecture. I would like to encapsulate all cell manipulations within the every column/.style={} callback.
MWE
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\tikzset{
    pics/powerOutlet/.style={
       code={
          \draw[red,very thick](-250,200)--(250,200);
          \draw[red,very thick,line cap=round](-250,450) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=250];
          \draw[red,very thick](0,-50)--(0,200);
          \node[inner sep=0mm]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ElectricComponent/label}};
      }
    },
    pics/ElectricComponent/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{ElectricComponent/.cd, #1}
            \pic{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ElectricComponent/type}};
        }
    },
    ElectricComponent/type/.initial={powerOutlet},
    ElectricComponent/label/.initial={},
 }

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
A;B
1;2 
3;4
5;6
\end{filecontents}

\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
\pgfplotstablecreatecol{Hash}{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\csvdataDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\pgfplotstableset{
    verb string type,
    columns={Hash,A,B},
    assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
    every column/.style={
        assign cell content/.code={
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Hash}}{
                \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/@cell content}{TEST-Value}
            }{}
        },
    },
}

\begin{document}
    \pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.1mm,y=-0.1mm]
       \foreach \row in {0,...,\csvdataDataRows}{
          \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Hash}\of{\csvdata}
          \pic[transform shape] at (2,2){
             ElectricComponent={
                label={\pgfplotsretval},
%               label={TEST-Label},
             }
          };
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

OUTPUT

EXPECTED OUTPUT


@cfr not quoting it doesn't improve the behavior. And in the past I made the observation, that I have to quote it. You mean, why I don't use .code={} within the \tikzset? It is not working without the .style. I think this hint I got in another question.

I don't really see why \pgfmath in that case b/c you're not trying to evaluate it?

@cfr This was just to store the value of \pgfplotsretval within \l. I changed it now and take immediately \pgfplotsretval. But no change in the result.

@cfr I think it is more a question of when the table content is created and when the TikZ picture trys to use this data. Because when I fill in these data within the \pgfplotstablecreatecol function this will work. But I don't want to do it there, because I do a lot of customizing and manupulation within the every column/.style callback.

I wasn't suggesting it would fix anything. (I should have added 'off-topic'.)

Your
every column/.style={
        assign cell content/.code={
            \ifthenelse{\equal{\pgfplotstablecolname}{Hash}}{

only controls the content of the column in this instance of typesetting. The values will not actually be stored in the table.
The manual even lists assign cell content in the part of Typesetting Cell Content.
I'd suggest to actually create the values with \pgfplotstablecreatecol:
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code=
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{TEST-Value}
]{Hash}{\csvdata}

See the link to use values of other rows and columns.

I also want to point out that using \pgfplotstablegetelem inside a loop “is quite slow”. There might be better ways to loop through all the values for your TikZ picture. I've added an alternative with \pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement. Of course this will depend on your real use-case in the end.
Code
\documentclass[border=6pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\tikzset{
    pics/powerOutlet/.style={
       code={
          \draw[red,very thick](-250,200)--(250,200);
          \draw[red,very thick,line cap=round](-250,450) arc[start angle=180,end angle=360,radius=250];
          \draw[red,very thick](0,-50)--(0,200);
          \node[inner sep=0mm]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ElectricComponent/label}};
      }
    },
    pics/ElectricComponent/.style={
        code={
            \tikzset{ElectricComponent/.cd, #1}
            \pic{\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/ElectricComponent/type}};
        }
    },
    ElectricComponent/type/.initial={powerOutlet},
    ElectricComponent/label/.initial={},
 }

\begin{filecontents}{data.csv}
A;B
1;2
3;4
5;6
\end{filecontents}
\pgfplotstableread[col sep=semicolon]{data.csv}{\csvdata}
%  actually create the contents of the column as well:
\pgfplotstablecreatecol[
  create col/assign/.code=
    \pgfkeyssetvalue{/pgfplots/table/create col/next content}{TEST-Value}
]{Hash}{\csvdata}

\pgfplotstablegetrowsof{\csvdata}
\pgfmathtruncatemacro\csvdataDataRows{\pgfplotsretval-1}

\pgfplotstableset{
    verb string type,
    columns={Hash,A,B},
    assign column name/.style={/pgfplots/table/column name={\textbf{#1}}},
}

\begin{document}
\pgfplotstabletypeset{\csvdata}

\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.1mm,y=-0.1mm]
\foreach \row in {0,...,\csvdataDataRows}{
  \pgfplotstablegetelem{\row}{Hash}\of{\csvdata}
  \pic[transform shape] at (2,2){
     ElectricComponent={label=\pgfplotsretval}
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=0.1mm,y=-0.1mm]
\pgfplotstableforeachcolumnelement{Hash}\of\csvdata\as\HASH{%
  \pic[transform shape] at (2,2){
     ElectricComponent={label=\HASH}
  };
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


Hmm I would like to avoid using the \pgfplotstablecreatecol callback, because I do a lot of consistency tests and customization within the assign cell content/.code function. Is there no way to store the values within this function and not only control the content of the column in this instance of typesetting?

@Pascal I don't understand. The create col/assign code is used to store the values (directly in the table). Why couldn't you do all your consistency tests and customization there? This will only be evaluated once that way. You can of course also just store the result somewhere else (depending on the row index) and then just use that and not even PGFPlotsTable anymore.

I can not do everything there, because there are a lot of other (completely independent from the hash column) tasks to do. I handle all these tasks in a function which is quit similar to a stack handling routine and it would be great to have everything encapsulated there. Hmm yes, I also thought about creating a shadow copy of these values, but this will slow me down. Right now, my input .csv has about 25 columns and 1000 rows. But I think your hint regaring the differences between "Typesetting" and "data storage" was helpful for me. I will see what I can do here. Thank you!
